# XSL percentile function

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is there way how to get 90, 95 or 99 percentile from input values with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0? Below is a code from this question [How to print percentile using xsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41819379/how-to-print-percentile-using-xsl), but is is not working correctly. This gives me a avarage from two values and not one value which is that wanted percentil.

> From this "online calculator" is result 5. https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/probability-statistics/percentile-calculator/?i=2%2C4%2C3%2C1%2C5&p=90&steps=on

XML

```
<root>
    <value t="5"></value>
    <value t="1"></value>
    <value t="2"></value>
    <value t="4"></value>
    <value t="3"></value>
</root>
```

XSL

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="thisPercentile">
         <xsl:call-template name="percentiles">
            <xsl:with-param name="responsetimes" select="/root/*/@t" />
            <xsl:with-param name="percentile" select="0.9" />
         </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:value-of select="$thisPercentile" />
    </xsl:template>



<xsl:template name="percentiles">
   <xsl:param name="responsetimes" select="." />
   <xsl:param name="percentile" select="." />
   <xsl:variable name="sortedresponsetimes">
        <xsl:for-each select="$responsetimes">
            <xsl:sort data-type="number" />
            <xsl:element name="time">
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:variable>
   <xsl:variable name="n" select="count($responsetimes)-1" />
   <xsl:variable name="k" select="floor($percentile*$n)+1" />
   <xsl:variable name="f" select="($percentile*$n+1)-$k" />
   <xsl:variable name="a0" select="$sortedresponsetimes[1]/time[$k]" />
   <xsl:variable name="a1" select="$sortedresponsetimes[1]/time[$k+1]" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$a0 + ( $f * ( $a1 - $a0))" />
</xsl:template>
```

Ouput after transform

> 4.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XPath 3.1 making use of the `sort` function you could implement that algorithm given on the linked page as

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:percentile" as="xs:decimal">
      <xsl:param name="input-sequence" as="xs:decimal*"/>
      <xsl:param name="p" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="let $sorted-input := sort($input-sequence),
                            $i := round($p div 100 * count($sorted-input))
                            return $sorted-input[$i]"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

in a complete sample as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:function name="mf:percentile" as="xs:decimal">
      <xsl:param name="input-sequence" as="xs:decimal*"/>
      <xsl:param name="p" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="let $sorted-input := sort($input-sequence),
                            $i := round($p div 100 * count($sorted-input))
                            return $sorted-input[$i]"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:value-of select="mf:percentile(value/@t, 90)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFukv8u

In XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can use `perform-sort` and then local XSLT variables in the function:

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:percentile" as="xs:decimal">
      <xsl:param name="input-sequence" as="xs:decimal*"/>
      <xsl:param name="p" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:variable name="sorted-input" as="xs:decimal*">
          <xsl:perform-sort select="$input-sequence">
              <xsl:sort select="."/>
          </xsl:perform-sort>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:variable name="i" select="round($p div 100 * count($sorted-input))"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="$sorted-input[$i]"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/3Nqn5Yc

Comment: Well, if you want to output that value computed from the other document then `<xsl:value-of select="mf:percentile(document(root/file[1]/@filename)/root/value/@t, 90)"/>` should do.